# Getting Error " raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, api, ssl, https, python-requests

I am executing an HDFC Bank API and I need to send SSL certificate to verify the identity. And for that I am using requests library of python. But I am getting an error

> Raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='openapiuat.hdfcbank.com', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: /API/IMPSPayment (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336445449, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3717)')))"

```
cert_file_path = "newArhamCert.crt"
key_file_path = "newArhamPrivate.key"

cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)

json_payload = {
                "RequestSignatureEncryptedValue": RequestSignatureEncryptedValue,
                "SymmetricKeyEncryptedValue": SymmetricKeyEncryptedValue,
                "Scope": "**********",
                "TransactionId": "12122020DECARH3",
                "OAuthTokenValue": accessToken,
               }

convertes_json = json.dumps(json_payload, indent = 4)

headers = {
            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
            'apikey' : '***************************************',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           } 

endpoint_url = 'https://openapiuat.hdfcbank.com:9443/API/IMPSPayment'

json_responce = requests.post(endpoint_url, headers=headers, data=convertes_json, cert=cert)

print(json_responce.text)
```